# Как раставить Constrains в Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, objective-c, autolayout

[image]

Прямоугольник с черной обводкой - это UIView с изменяемой высотой.
В UIView находятся три линии (UIImageView).

Вопрос:

Как проставить ограничения так, чтобы при изменении высоты UIView расстояние от красной линии до нижнего края UIView (Static height) оставалось постоянным, а расстояния между другими линиями (Height A, Height B, Height C) изменялись равнозначно (т.е Height A == Height B == Height C)

После изменения высоты UIView:

[image]

Comment: Я бы сделал следующее:
 1. Установил фиксированный размер StaticHeight
 2. Установил фиксированное позиционирование StaticHeight (например: 0px от нижней строчки до нижней планки View)
 3. Выделил бы 3 верхних view и указал им "Equal Heights"
 4. Так же зафиксировал бы расстояния между "линиями".

Все :) на своем примере - у меня получилось авто-распределение в зависимости от глобального UIView